# My app crashes with the information: "objc[94875]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both..."

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10

**I run my app in the simulator，when I try to save a picture to the system album, the app stopped unexpectedly with the information:**"*objc[94875]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x122124910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x121851210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.*"
**How to solve this problem? thanks!**
[screenshot of crash information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntlbR.png)